# How to disable TE.ProcessHost.Managed.exe in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

We have a solution with multiple projects and one of them is an nunit unit tests project with over 1000 tests.  I'm assuming it's because we have unit tests in the solution that this thing fires up every time we open the solution.

We use TeamCity to run the unit tests for us, so the only time we'd be running them locally would be if we're adding or changing tests - so I rarely have need for this thing.

TE.ProcessHost.Managed.exe literally occupies more ram than devenv.exe, and fires up at random times sucking up CPU.

I've tried unchecking **Test - Test Settings - Keep Test Execution Engine Running** but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I can kill the process, but it eventually comes back.

Is there no reasonable way to turn this thing off until I actually need it?

Thanks-